# transforming an apache rewrite to an nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite

i had a project in which i had to redirect all not found files to the index.php. I did this in apache with placing a .htaccess file in my project folder. the file's contents are--

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

now i wanted the same in nginx. here is how my nginx.conf looks like

```
root   /usr/local/apache2/htdocs;
index  index.php index.html index.htm;
location /project/ {
            root   /usr/local/apache2/htdocs;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
}
```

now whenever i make a request like `http://localhost/project/hello` then this request should go to `http://localhost/project/index.php` but this says `File not found`.

Now why i thought this would work is because since the `root` directive inside the location block overrides the `root` directive outside the block (though there values are same), the rewrite module would look for `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/project/index.php`. 
What am i missing here?

**UPDATE**

This configuration works

```
root   /usr/local/apache2/htdocs;
location /project/ {
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;    #effectively root here is /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
            try_files $uri $uri/ /project/index.php;
 }
```

But i dont see why this should work because as pointed out in the docs [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root) directory matched in the location block is appended to the value of `root` directive

Comment: I'm confused now... are you confused about the index directive or the try_files directive? The index directive refers only to a filename, not a directory path. Thus, if your URI references a directory within the `location` directive path, those files will be checked relative to that directory. try_files uses a full path / URI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 location /project/ {
             root   /usr/local/apache2/htdocs;
             index  index.php index.html index.htm;
-            try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
+            try_files $uri $uri/ /project/index.php;
 }
```

Perhaps you needed to specify the root in the URL? Otherwise, there is no reference point for the URL. The server can't guess at whatever directory it was last in or the user intended. If that doesn't accomplish what you want, comment back and I'll spin up a server to do a quick test on.

Comment: this time it works. but i dont get this. the `/project/` from location block is appended to the `root` directive's value as mentioned by the docs [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root)

Comment: @lovesh You're confusing prepending the root with prepending the location. `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs` is defined as where we start looking for the files, but if the URI doesn't include `/project/`, we won't reach this block. You have to specify `/project/` because the location directive is not prepended. If it were, you would never be able to redirect outside of this subdirectory.

Comment: alright i get it. When it looks for the file say `xyz.php` it will look in `root`+`location` but when it rewrites it uses the `root`+`rewrite_path` (+ means concatenation)

Comment: @lovesh No, it looks in root+uri. Root is defined by the URI. consider if you had another block like `location /project2/ { root /tmp; }`. Your rewrite path defines a new URI. Now imagine what happens if I declare `/project2/index.php` in the block from my answer. The server bases the root off that URI. The `location` directory still needs to exist in the `root` directory.